# How to prevent Cmake from creating Debug/Release folders under EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH?

Tags: cmake

I set `EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH` as `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin` but the executable is created in `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/Debug` or `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/Release`.

How can I make it put all output under `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin` without Debug/Release folders?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set variable [CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/variable/CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_CONFIG.html) to the directory which will be used "**as is**" for Debug builds. Similarly, for Release builds variable *CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE* is used.

While you may set both these variables to the *same value*, note that executables created for release builds will **overwrite** ones for debug builds, which is not natural with CMake.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using either Visual Studio or XCode. Thus, you might want to set [`RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.html) instead:

> Output directory in which to build RUNTIME target files.
>
> This property specifies the directory into which runtime target files should be built. The property value may use generator expressions. Multi-configuration generators (VS, Xcode) append a per-configuration subdirectory to the specified directory unless a generator expression is used.
>
> This property is initialized by the value of the variable CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY if it is set when a target is created.
>
> See also the RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_<CONFIG> target property.

Answer (score 0):

CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE all letter must be capital,i wrote as CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_Release and it didn't work.so stupid i am